# Retrieve the title of a stored plist value from localized .strings

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, inappsettingskit

What is the best method to retrieve the title for the stored Root.plist value located inside Root.strings ? For example I have stored an INT = 1 which has a key of MUL_VAL_2 that corresponds to "Female Voice" in Root.strings.  How can I retrieve "Female Voice" for the stored INT?

```
 // Root.strings     
 "MUL_VALUE_TITLE"       = "Multiple Values";
 "MUL_VAL"               = "Sound Theme";
 "MUL_VAL_1"             = "Male Voice";
 "MUL_VAL_2"             = "Female Voice";
 "MUL_VAL_3"             = "Mechanical";


 // Root.plist
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
<key>Titles</key>
<array>
    <string>MUL_VAL_1</string>
    <string>MUL_VAL_2</string>
    <string>MUL_VAL_3</string>
</array>
<key>Type</key>
<string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
<key>Values</key>
<array>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
</array>
<key>Title</key>
<string>MUL_VAL</string>
<key>Key</key>
<string>timer_theme_mulValue</string>
<key>DefaultValue</key>
<integer>0</integer>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IASK's own logic to retrieve the localized string:

```
[settingsViewController.settingsReader titleForStringId:@"MUL_VAL_1"]
```

Comment: And of course, use [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MUL_VAL_%d", myInt] to actually generate the key.

Comment: Yeah, or you could use `[settingsReader specifierForKey:]` and `multipleTitles` to walk through the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to [load plist as NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a), retrieve the 'Title' key for your INT value, then get title from Root.strings for that key via `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` macro.

See also: [String resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) in Apple's docs.

Here how to do this:

```
int storedInt = 1;
NSString * plistName = @"Root";
NSString * stringsTableName = @"Root";

// Loading plist
NSString * myPlistFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary * rootPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:myPlistFilePath];

NSString * key = nil;
NSString * keyReadable = nil;

NSArray * values = rootPlist[@"Values"];
NSArray * titles = rootPlist[@"Titles"];
NSUInteger indexOfValue = [values indexOfObject:@(storedInt)];
if (indexOfValue != NSNotFound) {
    key = titles[indexOfValue];
    keyReadable = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, stringsTableName, @""); // Obtain readable title for key
} else {
    // handle 'undefined value in dictionary' error here.
}

NSLog(@"for value: %d key is: %@ and title of key is: %@", storedInt, key, keyReadable);
```

In the code above "your stored INT" is set in the `storedInt` variable. You can use, for example, for cycle to iterate over it's possible values.